# WSO2 IS Proxy : Do WSO2 has WSO2 IS Proxy?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I installed and configured WSO2 IS 5.0 But I would like the users access through the proxy. So I would like to know WSO2 has WSO2 IS Proxy or not? Or WSO2 has any product to use for this purpose?

Answer (score 7):

WSO2 has not any proxy related product.  Also, there are well known proxy such as Apache HTTP / Nginx and so on.  As i know,  WSO2 also recommends to use Nginx.  Please find details on how you can use proxy with WSO2IS from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/11/16/how-to-developing-identity-server-behind-proxy-or-load-balancer/)

Comment: Well said, This is the exact answer!

Answer (score 1):

I have used WSO2 IS in production with Nginx and it has worked correctly for me.

You can also review the official documentation [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/fronting-with-the-nginx-load-balancer/)

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 does not provide in-built proxy. However, you you can use well known proxy products for this purpose. Ex: Nginx, HA proxy etc.

If you deploy WSO2 products in cloud environments, you can can use cloud native LBs such as AWS ALB, Azure application gateway etc.

You need 443 LB listener port to forward traffic to 9443 port in WSO2 IS server.